# Include struct from header

Tags: c++, qt

How can one include a `struct` defined in an external header file into another file? At first, I passed the struct by pointer, so I only needed a forward declaration. But now I want to pass by value and can't make it compile. The header `lagerverwaltung.h` does include the struct, so where is the problem?

file `lagerverwaltung.h`:

```
#ifndef LAGERVERWALTUNG_H
#define LAGERVERWALTUNG_H

struct etikettInfo{
    QString userName;
    QList<struct properties_content *> inhalte;
};

class Lagerverwaltung : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ... and so on
};
#endif // LAGERVERWALTUNG_H
```

file `etikett1.h`:

```
#ifndef ETIKETT1_H
#define ETIKETT1_H

#include "lagerverwaltung.h" // for struct etikettInfo
class Lagerverwaltung;
//struct etikettInfo;

namespace Ui {
class Etikett1;
}

class Etikett1 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Etikett1(Lagerverwaltung *mainwindow,
                      etikettInfo etikettData,  // <- struct etikettInfo has not been declared
                      QWidget* parent = 0);
    ~Etikett1();

private:
    Ui::Etikett1 *ui;
    Lagerverwaltung *lgrvw;
    etikettInfo etikettData;   // <- struct etikettInfo does not name a type
};

#endif // ETIKETT1_H
```

If it matters: Both .h-files do have include guards.

Ok the error messages (see comments in code) are really quite descriptive but I don't know what I should do differently.

Comment: In etikett1.h you include lagerverwaltung.h which contains `struct etikettInfo` and `class Lagerverwaltung`. And right after that you re-declare `class Lagerverwaltung`. To me that looks like a bad thing to do. Also: please post the (relevant) error message.

Comment: The error message is inside the code (comments).

Comment: why not create a file `etikettInfo.h`, put the struct there and include it where you need it? (ps: the denglish is strong in you)

Comment: Ok valid point, but I assume this would not change anything?
in this project I mix languages up, my bad :/

Comment: @KompjoeFriek: redeclaring class as forward declaration is not a bad thing (it might point to badly arranged code, but it's not a problem)

Comment: @user2366975: error: 'struct etikettInfo has not been declared' suggest that some fwd decl is the only thing compiler sees, yet in your example fwd decl is commented out. Both errors appear at the same time?

Comment: Could the `Q_OBJECT` macro be causing it in some way? (I know nothing about Qt so don't know what this does)

Comment: Have you removed any lines from the code in the question (besides the definition of `Lagerverwaltung`)? Specifically, could accidentally be including `etikett1.h` inside `lagerverwaltung.h`? Or, might you possibly have another header with the include guard `LAGERVERWALTUNG_H` for example in another directory? One of those could cause the `Etikett1` being defined before `etikettInfo`.

Comment: You have been right. I mixed things up with including and forward-declaring `lagerverwaltung.h`. Now I exported the struct to a separate header and it works. Also I have been including `etikett1.h` inside of `lagerverwaltung.h` without needing to (moved it to implementation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands the

```
struct etikettInfo{
    QString userName;
    QList<struct properties_content *> inhalte;
};
```

needs the proper includes for this to be a properly declared struct. So add

```
#include <QString>
#include <QList>
```

as well as declaration for `properties_content`.

Answer (score 1):

> Also I have been including etikett1.h inside of lagerverwaltung.h

There's your bug. You include `etikett1.h` in `lagerverwaltung.h` which includes `etikett1.h` which includes `lagerverwaltung.h` and so on. In other words, you have a circular dependency. Your include guards prevent the infinite inclusion, but also cause one of the headers to be included before the other. In this case, `lagerverwaltung.h` was included first and before defining anything - `etikettInfo` in particular - it includes `etikett1.h`... which depends on `etikettInfo` which wasn't defined yet.

If `lagerverwaltung.h` truly depends on `etikett1.h` and the only thing `etikett1.h` depends on in `lagerverwaltung.h` is `etikettInfo` and nothing in `lagerverwaltung.h` depends on `etikettInfo` then the simplest solution is to split the definition of `etikettInfo` into another header and include that in `etikett1.h` instead of `lagerverwaltung.h`.